# When does inherit_errexit not work?

Tags: bash, exit-status

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
shopt -s inherit_errexit
a=$(cat no-such-file)
echo survived
```

```
$ /tmp/a.sh
cat: no-such-file: No such file or directory
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
shopt -s inherit_errexit
echo -n $(cat no-such-file)
echo survived
```

```
$ /tmp/a.sh
cat: no-such-file: No such file or directory
survived
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
shopt -s inherit_errexit
f() { :; }
f $(cat no-such-file)
echo survived
```

```
$ /tmp/a.sh
cat: no-such-file: No such file or directory
survived
```

Any other cases? Or some generalization?

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 covers most of the pitfalls associated with `set -e`

Comment: @Inian I read the page. The thing is, it's written in a "try this one, and this, and who knows what else awaits you"-way. As the author clearly suggests against using it. I wanted to have a more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL,DR: to benefit from `set -e`, directly assign the result of a command substitution to a variable (optionally with extra strings around it). Don't combine multiple command substitutions together or use a command substitution in a command argument.

The problem is not with `inherit_errexit`. It's working. The problem is the limitations of `set -e` (which aren't specific to bash: other sh-like shells have the same problem).

Demonstration: run this variant of your second example.

```
$ cat b2.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
shopt -s inherit_errexit
echo -n $(cat no-such-file; echo >&2 after cat)
echo survived
$ ./b2.sh 
cat: no-such-file: No such file or directory
survived
```

Note that `echo >&2 after cat` was not executed. It would be if `inherit_errexit` was off.

The problem is that `set -e` only stops the execution on error in simple cases. If a command substitution returns a failure status, that doesn't stop the execution of the simple command that contains the substitution. It might, at most, set the return status of the simple command, which might in turn stop the execution of the script. A “simple command” consists of assignments, redirections and an optional executable command name and arguments. If a redirection fails, the return status is 1. Otherwise, if there is a command name, the return status of the simple command is the return status of the executable command. Otherwise the return status is the return status of the last command substitution, or 0 if there is none. Here are some examples of simple commands:

- `true </no/such/file` → status 1 due to the failed redirection
- `false </dev/null` → status 1 from `false`
- `a=b` → status 0 due to not having any part that can fail
- `a=$(exit 0) b=$(exit 1) c=$(exit 2)` → status 2 from the last command substitution
- `a=$(exit 2) b=$(exit 1) c=$(exit 0)` → status 0 from the last command substitution
- `true $(exit 0) $(exit 1) $(exit 2)` → status 0 from `true`

Once again, in all cases, `set -e` will only halt the script if the status of the command is nonzero. The status of embedded commands is not directly relevant.

And so in your second script `echo -n $(…)` has the status 0, from `echo` (except if `echo` fails to write), regardless of what happens inside the command substitution. Therefore the script won't stop here even if `set -e` is active. Likewise, in the third script, `f $(…)` has the status 0 from `f`.

Comment: It should probably be noted here that the `local` builtin would ignore command substitution errors regardless of whether it's the last substitution or not.